# Were there humans off-planet in Horizon Zero Dawn?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Given how advanced humanity had become before it was wiped out by the Faro Virus it is not a stretch to think that there were bases off-planet with humans living on them.

Has this been confirmed one way or the other at all either in game, or by anyone outside of the game?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Maybe.**

They had the means to do so, however bad luck played a part.

The *Odyssey* was a colony ship crewed by 50-60 people, which brought 200,000 cryo-stored zygotes in space (datapoint [*Odyssey* Ready?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtWhIJ1Ybos)).

[image: Odyssey ready? datapoint]

Its goal was to "spawn a human population" on an unknown exoplanet, the name of which was corrupted (datapoint [*Odyssey* injustice?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFMJ4CG3oZQ)).

[image: Odyssey injustice? datapoint]

Unfortunately, the *Odyssey* seemingly failed, as read in the datapoint [*Odyssey* has failed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_F0OrApzJRc).

> All,
>
> Some terrible news, I'm afraid. Far Zenith has informed me that the *Odyssey* mission has failed. Last night, telemetry indicated a catastrophic antimatter containment failure as the drives spun up to depart the solar system. The ship, its crew, its cargo of zygotes and seeds, its alpha-build of APOLLO - all were lost.
>
> Zero Dawn is now the only hope for the continuation of the human species and Earthly life.
>
> We must succeed.
>
> Elisabet

However, the following post-credits scene hints at "so much never revealed",  especially "Masters",  who sent the signal that woke HADES.

We'll probably know for sure in *Horizon Forbidden West*!

Answer (score 6):

Spoilers for *Horizon Zero Dawn*:

> The mysterious signal that woke up Gaia’s subordinate functions and began the Derangement must have come from *somewhere*, so there’s at least an implicit suggestion of possible off-Earth technological activity.
>
> Also, an interstellar ship, the *Odyssey*, was under construction at the time of the Faro Plague, and they tried to speed up its completion but it was reported as destroyed. There is some speculation that this wasn’t actually the case.